# Using italics in geom_text() with variables in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some troubles with geom_text() and annotate(), respectively. First of all, I want to show the number of observations of my dot plot/barplot within the plot.
I have now solved it awkwardly via an additional vector in the dataframe where the number is stored.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)  
v1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
v2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
v3 <- c(13,67,89,280,40,1,23,99,32,1,75,280,270,200,196,450,320,277,23,4,1,2,5,89,45,23,11,1,3,23,100,100,100,100,100,200,100,11,6,6,123,100,100,100,100,100,12,86,11,390,75,100,110,19,299,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,11,100,120,110,100,100,423,100,279,100,100,100,12,100,100,75,5,10,10,10,10,10)
v4 <- c(4,NA,NA,NA,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,9,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,22,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,34,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

summary <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4)
summary$v1 <- as.factor(summary$v1)
summary$v2 <- as.factor(summary$v2)

ggplot(summary, aes(x = v1, y = v3, fill = v2)) + 
    geom_dotplot(binaxis  = "y", stackdir = "center", binwidth = 5, position = position_dodge(0.75), dotsize = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(v4>0, v4, NULL), y=500), position=position_dodge(width=0.75), vjust=-0.25, hjust=0)
```

Now I have a problem:

I would like to insert an "n" in italics before the number of observations (v4). I have done a lot of searching on this as well. One solution I found was `substitute(paste0(italic('n='), summary$v4))`, but here I get the following error:
`Error in rep(yes, length.out = len) :  attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'.`

If I use the following code: `expression(paste0(italic('n='), summary$v4))`
The "n=" is displayed in italic, but the variable is treated as text and the content of the variable is not displayed.

[here an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKYjG.png)

Probably there is also an automatic solution how to count the number of observations automatically. Also here I would be very happy about improvements and help.

Comment: Perhaps try adding `parse=TRUE` to the call to `geom_text(..)` . If that doesn't work can you paste the code with the replacement so we can see where that goes. I think it goes in the `v4` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse = TRUE` in `geom_text`

```r
ggplot(summary, aes(x = v1, y = v3, fill = v2)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis  = "y", stackdir = "center", binwidth = 5, 
               position = position_dodge(0.75), dotsize = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(!is.na(v4), paste0('italic(n) == ', v4), ''), 
                y = 500), vjust = -0.25, hjust = 0, parse = TRUE,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works well! However, just a minor question: is there any possibility to get rid of the blank characters between n and the equality sign? That would be great.